# findOneAndUpdate() returns null in value on upsert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongodb and mongoose.

Please help me out! I'm stuck in this problem that I describe below.

I have this static method that I call from a controller(a router).

```
IDCounterSchema.statics.getNextID = function(collectionName, callback){

    this.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
        {name: collectionName},
        {$inc: {sequence:1}},
        {new: true, upsert: true},
        callback
    );
};
```

But, when I call this on the first time after the initial app launch, it returns null in value.

```
{ lastErrorObject: { updatedExisting: false, n: 0 },
  value: null,
  ok: 1 } // 1 means the execution succeeded 
          // in fact, i see the inserted data in mongo database.
```

According to [this mongodb document](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#findandmodify-value-field), it shouldn't be null when upsert&new properties are true.

Because I get null in value property of the returned object, it leads to this error and crush my application.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sequence' of null
```

But, after the second launch of application, when I call the same static method, it works fine without getting any errors.

Any idea how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the 2.0 node.js native driver [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate), the option that controls whether `findOneAndUpdate` returns the original or new document is called `returnOriginal`, not `new`.

So your code would need to look like this instead:

```
this.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    {name: collectionName},
    {$inc: {sequence:1}},
    {returnOriginal: false, upsert: true},
    callback
);
```

But it would probably be better to do this directly in Mongoose by using [`Model.findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) where the option *is* named `new`:

```
this.findOneAndUpdate(
    {name: collectionName},
    {$inc: {sequence:1}},
    {new: true, upsert: true},
    callback
);
```

The docs you link to are for `findAndModify` in the MongoDB shell, where the option is also named `new`. Very confusing.

Comment: @Hayatomo Hmm...I don't know, it worked fine when I tried it with Mongoose 4.3.7. The structure of the arguments to your callback are different with Mongoose, is that maybe what you're seeing?

Comment: Both code did work! I didn't notice that the structure of returned object is different when executing the first code and the second code, so I needed to do some work to make the second code work.

Comment: Even with returnOriginal as false, when a document is inserted I get null back. Whereas if the document is updated I get the value back as expected